# .exe file created with pyinstaller shuts down immediately when i run it

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to create a simple app using qt5(qt designer) and pyintsaller for exe file. I successfully created a exe file but when i execute it, command line windows pop ups for a second and closes immediately. When I run the code in IDE or text editor it works fine. Do you have any idea what I am missing here. My code looks like this.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(462, 443)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 70, 161, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(27)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 170, 151, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 462, 18))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "HELLO"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I would suggest you try to run the executable  from a DOS prompt. This will often allow  you to see error messages that will provide a clue to what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

tested with pyinstaller 3.5 . working

[image]

Comment: Yes, your life saver. i was using 3.3.1 version, i install 3.5 version and now its working.Thanks